# Odd even sequence java 2 thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to write a program with two Java threads. One shall print odd and the other shall print even numbers. The output should be in sequence. My code is not working properly. Please correct it and tell me what was the error.

```java
public class App {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ThrdO to=new ThrdO();
    Thread t1=new Thread(to);

    ThredE te=new ThredE();
    Thread t2=new Thread(te);
    t1.start();


    t2.start();
 }

}

public class ThrdO implements Runnable{

  PrintCl pcl =new PrintCl();

  @Override
  public void run() {
    for(int i=0;i<10;i+=2)
    pcl.Even(i);    
  }
}


public class ThredE implements Runnable {

    PrintCl pcl =new PrintCl();

    @Override
    public void run() {
      for(int i=1;i<10;i+=2)
        try {
          pcl.odd(i);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
        }   
     }

public class PrintCl {
    public void Even(int n) {
      synchronized (this) {
        System.out.println(n);
        this.notifyAll();
        try {
            this.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }         
    }

    public void odd(int n) throws InterruptedException {

        synchronized (this) {
          System.out.println(n);
          this.notifyAll();
          this.wait();  
        }
    }
}
```

getting output

> 0 ,1

Comment: There are several issues with your code. To start off, you are locking on different instances `PrintCl pcl =new PrintCl();` . `synchronized (this) ` will lock on *separate* instances of `pcl`

Comment: @TheLostMind ohhh .. now i am changing my code

Comment: @TheLostMind that was a mistake in my code ..i never noticed that , now it working properly thank you

Comment: Create `PrintCl pcl =new PrintCl();` outside the *runnable* implementations and use the same instance of `PrintCl` in both cases

Comment: Funny how `TrdO`=even and `ThredE`=odd :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a much cleaner way of achieving what you want, without ugly sleeps in the code, not to mention that it will run faster than code with a sleep in it, for obvious reasons.

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrintCl pcl = new PrintCl();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThrdEven(pcl));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThrdOdd(pcl));

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}

public class ThrdEven implements Runnable {

    private PrintCl pcl = null;

    public ThrdEven(PrintCl pcl) {
        this.pcl = pcl;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i += 2) {
            pcl.Even(i);
        }
    }
}

public class ThrdOdd implements Runnable {

    private PrintCl pcl = null;

    public ThrdOdd(PrintCl pcl) {
        this.pcl = pcl;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i += 2) {
            pcl.odd(i);
        }
    }
}

public class PrintCl {

    private final Object _lock = new Object();
    private boolean isEvenAllowed = true;

    public void Even(int n) {
        synchronized (this._lock) {
            while (!this.isEvenAllowed) {
                try {
                    this._lock.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
            System.out.println(n);
            this.isEvenAllowed = false;
            this._lock.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    public void odd(int n) {
        synchronized (this._lock) {
            while (this.isEvenAllowed) {
                try {
                    this._lock.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
            System.out.println(n);
            this.isEvenAllowed = true;
            this._lock.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Its definitely a cleaner approach , just a suggestion `while (!this.isEvenAllowed)` can be replaced with `if (!this.isEvenAllowed)`

Comment: @Shirish: You are right that it would work in this case because there are only 2 threads competing with each other.  But it's standard practice to do it this way and more general purpose, as described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html). In particular, notice where it says _**Note:** Always invoke wait inside a loop that tests for the condition being waited for. Don't assume that the interrupt was for the particular condition you were waiting for, or that the condition is still true._

Answer (score 2):

Please try following changes in your code:

```
public class App {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

  PrintCl pcl =new PrintCl();

  ThrdO to=new ThrdO();
  to.setPcl(pcl);
  Thread t1=new Thread(to);

  ThredE te=new ThredE();
  te.setPcl(pcl);
  Thread t2=new Thread(te);
  t1.start();
  Thread.sleep(1000);
  t2.start();

 }
}
```

And for Thrd0:

```
public class ThrdO implements Runnable  {

  PrintCl pcl =null;

  @Override
  public void run() {
    for(int i=0;i<10;i+=2)
    pcl.Even(i);

  }

  public PrintCl getPcl() {
    return pcl;
  }

  public void setPcl(PrintCl pcl) {
    this.pcl = pcl;
  }


}
```

ThredE:

```
public class ThredE implements Runnable {

  PrintCl pcl =null;

  @Override
  public void run() {
    for(int i=1;i<10;i+=2)
        try {
            pcl.odd(i);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

  }

  public PrintCl getPcl() {
    return pcl;
  }

  public void setPcl(PrintCl pcl) {
    this.pcl = pcl;
  }
}
```

Comment: FYI: There is no guarantee that this will always work as expected.  For this to work, it expects `t1` to reach the synchronized block before `t2` at the very beginning.  But this is not guaranteed to happen.  The other more minor problem is that one of the threads never shuts down cleanly.

Comment: @sstan i didnt get that particular case

Comment: That's the fun with concurrency programming.  You'll have to run it multiple times before you see it, maybe :)  But when you do, you'll see something like 1, 0, 3, 2, ...

Comment: @sstan yyaaaa its happening .. how can i control this issue

Comment: I'll see if I can post an answer for you.

Comment: I have put `sleep` for thread. Now you can all the time run thread `t1` first.

Comment: @sstan your answer is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has two basic problems

1. Every thread have its own  `printing resource` . Hence once printing their first number they are waiting for notification endlessly.
2. Once you will fix this issue , Another issue is your one thread will be finished but second thread would still be waiting for its notification and it will never die.

I have fixed both issues in below code

```
 public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        PrintCl pcl =new PrintCl();
        ThrdO to=new ThrdO(pcl);
        Thread t1=new Thread(to);

        ThredE te=new ThredE(pcl);
        Thread t2=new Thread(te);
        t1.start();
        Thread.sleep(1000);// just to ensure that T1 should start first
        t2.start();
    }


}
class ThrdO implements Runnable{


    private PrintCl pcl;

    public ThrdO(PrintCl pcl) {
        this.pcl = pcl;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i=0;i<10;i+=2) {
            try {
                pcl.Even(i);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        synchronized (pcl){
            System.out.println("Releasing lock on pcl");
            pcl.notify();
        }
        System.out.println("ThrdO has finished its working");
    }
}

class ThredE implements Runnable {

    PrintCl pcl ;

    public ThredE(PrintCl pcl) {

        this.pcl = pcl;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i += 2) {
            try {
                pcl.odd(i);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        synchronized (pcl){
            System.out.println("Releasing lock on pcl ");
            pcl.notify();
        }
        System.out.println("ThredE has finished its working");

    }
}

    class PrintCl {
        public void Even(int n) throws InterruptedException {
            synchronized (this) {
                System.out.println("even - "+n);
                this.notifyAll();
                    this.wait();
            }
        }

        public void odd(int n) throws InterruptedException {

            synchronized (this) {
                System.out.println("odd "+n);
                this.notifyAll();
                this.wait();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: how you ensure T1 should enter for processing first every time

Comment: Thats a good question ? introduce a sleep() between start of T1 and T2 ?  I have modified the code . Please let me know if its ok .

Comment: Sleep is such a bad idea.

Comment: Agreed. but considering this simple use case / problem statement its not that bad.